# VBA INSERT INTO statement (MS Access)

Tags: vba

I am having a problem with below and getting a runtime error 3134

```
LastOrderNumber = DMax("Order", "Model_types")
NewOrderNumber = CLng(LastOrderNumber + 1)

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Model_types (Order) " _
            & "VALUES (" & NewOrderNumber & ")"
```

The field 'Order' in Model_types is a Long Integer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your database.  The error seems to indicate Order is a long int and I'd suspect NewOrderNumber is an integer or similar.  In any event its a data type mismatch

Answer (score 2):

Order is a reserved word. You should change your statement to :

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Model_types ([Order]) " _
        & "VALUES (" & NewOrderNumber & ")"
```